# Recipe review questions?

Tags: discussion

Are recipe review questions allowed? If someone wants to ask something like "I made this recipe, I expect effects to be like that, are there any mistakes?", would this be on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are allowed, but you'll likely find it hard to get a definitive answer since everything past style guidelines is purely subjective and debatable.  What one person smells or tastes could be indistinguishable by another.

Comment: But doesn't this sort of go against how stack exchange is supposed to work.  Or does that just go to the wayside.  Its about upvoting the best opinion when it comes to a "what's your opinion on this recipe" type question?  This is an ongoing debate I think when applying SE to this type of topic.  I just like to continue to get different takes on when people think.